# Is copy-paste of views in Interface Builder an unadvisable user behaviour?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

**Background:**
My workflow for developing interfaces for mobile apps depends on Illustrator and Photoshop. I'm not a fan of Interface Builder, nor am I impressed by the Android UI designer in Eclipse (haven't tried IntelliJ yet).  It's awkward to take an experience of laying out UI from such apps, and translate into IB.  Once in a while I try again to build a UI in IB, only to get bogged down in bad experiences.

The current problem I'm having is this:
When selecting a set of well-laid-out views within a View Controller's view from an iPhone storyboard, and then pasting into the corresponding View Controller view of the iPad storyboard, the views are all messed up.   They get thrown all over the canvas, and the size manipulation handles are hidden because they're not within the bounds of the superview.

**Is copying and pasting inappropriate behaviour in Interface Builder? Must I drag everything out of the library again?**

Side note: I'm working on a 13-inch screen, and the iPad view is larger than the small area given to work with.  I zoom out so I can actually see the whole thing, then select a component to adjust it, and find IB automatically zooming back in.

I've found question-answers saying the auto-zoom cannot be disabled, and so I have to just put up with that awkward UX.

Comment: The fact that your views are messed up when copying and pasting perhaps suggests that layout constraints are not well set up - or that you are not using constraint-based layout at all.

Comment: That's right, I have not been using auto-layout.  But does that matter? If it does, okay.  But I would still hope that a copy-paste operation would maintain either of the origin, or the size, of a source views, but in fact neither size nor origin of the frames are retained.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I wanted to share something, Sometimes Xcode will mess up the view when doing this, I experienced it today, especially about custom views. Im sure I have setup the nibs properly with the connections and stuff, but when running the view was not shown, although the class awakeFromNib was called. Be careful doing copy paste XIB views.

Comment: @otakuProgrammer In my opinion, it's never bad form to post on "an old" thread if there isn't any conclusive solution.  Thanks.  There are still many-year-old bugs and problems in Apple software that go un-fixed due to lack of interest at Apple. These issues tend to get solved only when a hundred people all complain at the same time.

Comment: In my experience, even a view properly set up with auto layout and no warnings won't copy properly. Frustrating when you have similar designs and have spent a lot of time on the auto layout, then you have to do it all over again. Not a very productive tool. Feels like it's still in beta. :)